# How to make outlook mail attachment from memory?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

Adding new `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` to `Outlook.MailItem.Attachments` via `Attachments.Add()` results in an `System.ArgumentException: 'Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.'`

Trying to add a JPEG image encoded in Base64 as an attachment to a mail item in Outlook. I am storing encoded image as a variable, converting it to a memory stream, then to an attachment.

```cs
public void CreateMessageWithAttachment() {
    Outlook.MailItem mailIttem = thisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    string base64Attachment = "/...base64 gibberish";
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Attachment));
    ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(ms, ct);

    attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "look_at_dis.jpg";
    mailIttem.Subject = "Test e-mail message with attachment";
    mailIttem.To = "friend@company.com";
    mailIttem.Body = "This message has been generated programmatically";
    mailIttem.Attachments.Add(attachment); // This raises "Sorry..." expression
    mailIttem.Display(true);
}
```

Raises `System.ArgumentException: 'Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.'`, which tells me nothing :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MailItem.Attachments.Add` only allows to pass a string (a fully qualified path to a file) or another Outlook item (e.g. `MailItem`) as the parameter.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only), it is only taking an `IStream` (you are supposed to open `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` as `IStream` using `IAttach::OpenProperty`). If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it allows to pass a url, a file name, another Outlook item, `IStream` or `IStorage` COM interface, another attachment (`Outlook.Attachment` or `Redemption.RDOAttachment` or `IAttach` MAPI interface) or an array (of Variant or of byte) to [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).[Attachments](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachments.htm).`Add`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 3):

[Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add?view=outlook-pia) gave me an impression that `Attachments.Add` is only supposed to really work with file paths, so saving `MemoryStream` to a temporary file and attaching it solved the problem.

```cs
string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempPath() + "look_at_dis.jpg";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create);

ms.CopyTo(fs);
fs.Close();

mailIttem.Attachments.Add(tempFilePath, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, "look_at_dis.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you attach the memory stream to the message, I believe you must reset its position to zero:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64Attachment));
ms.Position = 0; // important
ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(ms, ct);
// etc
```