Drag and drop files and emails issues
I have been working on a project which includes a drag and drop function. What I would like to create is an application where the end user can drag and drop files and/or emails that will be added to a database as a blob. The issue is that an email is not processed correctly. Files are put correctly in the database without an issue. But when I drop an email I have tried several ways but I always run into an issue. The code below works for the files but returns an error with the emails. The error states Cannot convert an object of the type System.IO.MemoryStream to the type OutlookItems.
This is the code that I am using at the moment:
Private Sub dgvDragDrop_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles dgvDragDrop.DragEnter

        ' Check if the dragged data contains Outlook item(s) or files
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent("RenPrivateMessages") Or e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
            ' Allow copying of the dragged data
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End If

    End Sub



 Private Sub dgvDragDrop_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles dgvDragDrop.DragDrop

        Try
            ' Check if the dragged data contains Outlook items
            If e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor") Then
                Dim dataObj As IDataObject = e.Data
                Dim formats As String() = dataObj.GetFormats()

                For Each format As String In formats
                    If format.Contains("RenPrivateMessages") Then
                        ' Get the dragged Outlook items
                        Dim outlookItems As OutlookItems = CType(e.Data.GetData(format), OutlookItems)

                        ' If Outlook items are present, process them as mail items
                        If outlookItems IsNot Nothing Then
                            For Each outlookItem As Object In outlookItems
                                If TypeOf outlookItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                                    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(outlookItem, Outlook.MailItem)

                                    ' Convert the mail item to a byte array
                                    Dim emailData As Byte() = GetEmailData(mailItem)

                                    ' Get the subject of the email
                                    Dim subject As String = mailItem.Subject

                                    ' Add the email data to the database
                                    AddEmailToDatabase(subject, emailData)
                                End If
                            Next

                            MessageBox.Show("Emails added to the database successfully.")
                            Exit Sub ' Exit the method if Outlook items are processed
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
                ' Get the array of file paths from the dragged data
                Dim files As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

                ' Process each dragged file
                For Each filePath As String In files
                    ' Get the file name and extension
                    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
                    Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(filePath)

                    ' Read the file data into a byte array
                    Dim fileData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)

                    ' Add the file data to the database
                    AddFileToDatabase(fileName, fileExtension, fileData)
                Next
            End If

            MessageBox.Show("Items added to the database successfully.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

Does anyone have any suggestion?
Update 8/5 Just a little extra info - when I save the mailitem first it does work.
Thanks

it is for c# but it easily converted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54695041/how-to-make-outlook-mail-attachment-from-memory

Thanks for your answer but I am not sure which part would apply to my problem? Are you referring to Redemption?

no thought of Александр Ложкин answer
